# Is there a way to data bind a single item without eg. a Repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Lets say I have a single object of type Car which I want to render as HTML:

```
class Car {
  public int Wheels { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to use the ASP.NET Repeater or ListView controls to bind because it seems too verbose. I just have the one object. But I still want to be able to use the databinding syntax so I won't have to use Labels or Literals. Something like:

```
<div>
  Wheels: <%# (int)Eval("Wheels") %><br />
  Model: <%# (string)Eval("Model") %>
</div>
```

Does anybody know about a control out there that does just that?

And I am not ready to switch to ASP.NET MVC just yet.

---

Unfortunately, the DetailsView control doesn't satisfy my needs because it doesn't seem to support the template-style syntax that I am after. It, too, needs to be bound to a DataSource object of a kind.

I liked better the solution Maxim and Torkel suggested. I will try to go for that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if the page is about a specific item (For exemple, Car.aspx?CarID=ABC123), I normally have a public property on the page called "CurrentCar"

```
public Car CurrentCar { get; set; }
```

And I can then have the following:

```
<div>
  Wheels: <%= CurrentCar.Wheels %><br />
  Model: <%= CurrentCar.Model %>
</div>
```

That allow you to have type safety. Just make sure to have a valid object assigned before the actual rendering.

Comment: Though you may want to check for CurrentCar being null here before displaying this markup.

Comment: I would make the property 'protected' instead of 'public', unless I had a reason to expose it to other classes (aside from subclasses like the ASPX page, of course.)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you make car a protected property on the page, this will allow you to access it directly in the aspx page:

```
<div>
  Wheels: <%= Car.Wheels %>
  Wheels: <%= Car.Models %>
</div>
```

This approach is actually better for single item databinding scenarios as the "binding" is strongly typed.

Comment: Wheels and Wheels. :P You got a typo there.

Answer (score 0):

One drawback of the protected property solution is that you cannot use it to bind to properties of controls.

For example, the following would not work:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Probably a truck" Visible='<%# CurrentCart.Wheels > 4 %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: And why have it protected? public is better in this case because 99.99% of the time, you don't inherit from the page elsewhere. Of course, the framework do but... that's it.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I want it to be protected... :)

Comment: Actually it DOES work with the <%# data binding syntax above... I had another problem that made it not work at first.